# How to use keywords as column names in Derby

Tags: sql, derby

Can I use reserved keywords as column names in Derby? 
I'm trying to migrate database schema into Derby for testing purposes. For that reason I don't really want to change the schema structure (column names etc).

So the question is, how can I create table with column name "open" in Derby? As for example table:

```
create table test ( open integer );
```

Tried to quote the column name, but so far no success...

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "open" at line 1, column 21.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: note that bot SQL Server and MySQL also support standard quoting using double quotes `"` - which I'd always prefer over the non-standard notation using the brackets or those dreaded backticks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way of quoting reserved words (and Derby follows the standard as nearly all DBMS do in that regard) is to use double quotes.

```
create table test ( "OPEN" integer );
```

But beware that once you do that column (or table) names become case-sensitive. `"OPEN"` is a different column than `"open"` or `"Open"`.

I would strongly suggest you do **not** use names that require you to quote them.

Comment: Ok, I swear that I did try that half a dozen times, and it did not work. But now it works... I'm writing tests for some legacy database, and can't really use the original DBMS in this case. But thanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Didn't know about that standard notation. Thanks. By the way, I know a few of these SQL standard stuff from books, But I can't find any book that covers the standard sql in more details (other than mere mortals which covers the basics and I think I read that in it) as a reference book. The standard ansi documentations as far as I know are expensive to buy. Do you know any book or articles that covers it in more details.

Comment: Hmm, this did not work for me at all in Derby 10.8.3.0
CREATE TABLE MyTable ("DESC" VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, ...) fails complaining about "DESC"